# create urls like Instagram posts or youtube video

Tags: python, django, software-design

I'm building a social network and I're going to create my own urls at random the question that has been on my mind for a long time is how to create urls like Instagram posts like Django like the following:

https://www.instagram.com/p/CeqcZdeoNaP/

or

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhRaaU9-Jg4

My problem is that on the one hand these urls have to be unique and on the other hand it does not make sense that on a large scale when the number of uploaded posts by the user is more than 100,000 I set unique = True Because the performance of the database decreases

Another point is the use of uuids, which solves this problem of uniqueness to a large extent, but the strings produced by uuid are very long, and if I shorten these strings and reduce the number of letters in the string, there is a possibility of a collision. And that several identical strings are produced

I wanted to know if there is a solution to this issue that generated urls are both short and unique while maintaining database performance

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might choose to design around ULIDs. https://github.com/ulid/spec

It's still 128 bits.
The engineering tradeoff they made was 48 bits of predictable low-entropy clock
catenated with an 80-bit nonce.

Starting with a timestamp makes it play very nicely with postgres B-trees.

They serialize 5 bits per character instead of the 4 bits offered by hex.
You could choose to go for 6 if you want, for the sake of brevity.

Similarly you could also choose to adjust the clock tick granularity,
and reduce its range.

Keeping the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) in mind,
you might choose to use a smaller nonce, as well.
The current design offers good collision resistance
up to around 2^40 identifiers per clock tick,
which might be overkill for your needs.